# How to Represent NOSQL-type data storage formats

Tags: json, database, diagram, nosql

I'm using a NOSQL (non-relational) type database for my thesis. More specifically storing in JSON encoded documents.

I've noticed, by reading other masterthesis that it is common practice to show a diagram representation of the data model used on the paper, however, I can't find any examples of this for my case.

Is there a proper way to do this? And should I even show a diagram explaining the JSON format?

## Edit

For the time being, I am using [this diagram](https://i.gyazo.com/14567996caa37c91e65e220642407d0b.png) to represent my NoSQL-type data, not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical data model applies equally well to a NoSQL database as it does to a relational database. I like to say, *there's always a schema*—even in so-called schemaless databases. It's just that your application code has to enforce the schema when you use NoSQL.

But the logical entities that your application uses must be described. An entity-relationship diagram is a good way of showing that.

It's less common in a NoSQL database to have lots of entities. Also, some NoSQL databases don't have any support for inter-entity relationships; they're all islands.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. It is descriptive of the data entities, fields, and relationships. You should label it as a *logical* data model design, because some people who are familiar with both SQL and NoSQL may be confused. It looks so much like what you'd see as a relational database diagram.